# How do I populate table fields with combobox selections in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a Combobox with 2 columns and I'm trying to get it to populate 2 fields in a table AfterUpdate. The code I have right now is:

```
    Private Sub ProductSelect_AfterUpdate()
    Product = ProductSelect.Column(0)
    Product2 = ProductSelect.Column(1)
    End Sub
```

But it only populates the "Product" field, not the "Product2" field. From everything I've read this should work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The correct code, I've found, is this:

```
    Private Sub ProductSelect_AfterUpdate()
    Me!Product = Me!ProductSelect.Column(0)
    Me!Product2 = Me!ProductSelect.Column(1)
    End Sub
```